# Problema con funciones y arrays

Tags: c

No entiendo porque el programa no realiza lo que ordeno hacer en las funciones y simplemente se imprime por pantalla los dos "printf" que uso de prueba en el main.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define MAX 10
void leerVect(int vect[MAX]);
void escribirVect (int v[MAX], int tam);


int main ()
{
    int v[MAX], tam=10;

    printf("empezamos\n");


    void leerVect(v);
    void escribirVect (v, tam);


    printf("Terminamos");



    return 0;
}

void leerVect(int v[MAX])
{
    int i;
        for (i=0; i<MAX && v[i]!=0; i++)
        {
            printf("Introduzca el valor de v[%d]\n", i);
            scanf("%d", &v[i]);
        }
}

void escribirVect (int v[MAX], int tam)
{
    int i;
    for (i=0; i<tam; i++)
    {
        printf("El valor de v[%d] es: %d \n", i, v[i]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Eso es porque en la función main cuando llamas a las funciones `leerVect` y `escribirVect` no debes escribir `void` eso quiere decir que no la función no retornará ningún valor y solo se usa cuando vas a declarar funciones.

Quedaría de la siguiente forma:

```
int main ()
{
    int v[MAX], tam=10;

    printf("empezamos\n");

    //Aqui no debe llevar void cuando llamas a las funciones
    leerVect(v);
    escribirVect (v, tam);


    printf("Terminamos");



    return 0;
}
```